# JTextArea no scroll bar

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, preferredsize

```
private JPanel contentPane;
public Driver() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 867, 502);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setBounds(10, 11, 831, 393);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    textArea.setText("dfgf");
    contentPane.add(scroll);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Driver frame = new Driver();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Why this doesn't not show the `textArea` with a scroll bar?

my problem is that I don't see even the textArea. but if I do `contentPane.add(scroll);` instead, I can see textArea but no scroll.

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: i posted the main part of my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"why this doesn not show the textArea with a scroll bar?"*

Because the viewport of the scrollpane has its own layout manager and is changing the position in the text area to suit its needs

The viewport will use the text area's preferred size property to determine how to lay it out. You can effect this value by adding text to the text area and/or setting the row/column properties according to your needs.

**Updated with example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestScrollPane03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestScrollPane03();
    }

    public TestScrollPane03() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
            
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(100, 50);
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(scrollPane);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

**Updated based on changes to question**

As camickr has already pointed out, the problem you are having is related to the how you are laying out your components.

This `contentPane.setLayout(null);` is just one of your many problems.  Stop using `null` layouts and start using appropriate layout managers.

Comment: i don't see the textarea, i can't see any text when i write to it

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with the layout of the scroll pane as well.  I'm assuming that since you're started using `setBounds` that you are trying to do your own layout instead of letting the layout manager API do it for your

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me

Comment: i posted my main part of code, i still don't know how to change it

Comment: This `contentPane.setLayout(null);` is your problem right here. Stop using `null` layouts and start using layout managers.

Comment: i removed it and it works. by the way, i didn't use it. this was auto generated by eclipse. thanks very much

Comment: can you tell me in brief why this fixed the problem? thank you

Comment: As Reimeus pointed out, the default size of any component is 0x0. Layout managers use a number of inputs to determine the how best size/position components.  The default layout manager for `JPanel` is FlowLayout.  You might like to change it to `BorderLayout` for your needs

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do you get such a nice cutout of the frame for that picture?

Comment: @syb0rg On the Mac, CMD+SHIFT+4 will bring up "target", you can use this to draw a rectangle around the area you want to capture, our press SPACE and capture the entire window

Comment: @MadProgrammer And you just eyeball it and get that shadow effect as well? It looks so perfect.

Comment: @syb0rg Actually I hit space bar, which turns the mouse cursor into a camera and click the window I want to capture and the Mac OS does it for me

Answer (score 2):

> why this doesn not show the textArea with a scroll bar

The scrollbar will in fact appear but without the "thumb grip" until you have appended enough text to your `JTextArea` to as to expand its size beyond the `JScrollPane` viewport size.

You're using `null` layout for your `contentPane` `JPanel`. This is never a good idea. Here your `JScrollPane` has a default size of `0 x 0` so never appears. There are plenty of [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) available for various sizing & positioning requirements.

Comment: the problem is that i don't see the textarea itself, like it was overwritten by something else

Comment: Yep, I'll chime in as well, if you're not using a layout manager, then use one. Otherwise you will encounter these types of problems.

Answer (score 2):

A scrollbar will appear automatically when the preferred size of the component added to the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scrollpane. You need to use layout managers for this to happen automatically

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setBounds(10, 11, 831, 393);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

You should NOT be using setBounds(). Instead you do something like:

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

Now when you load more then 5 lines of text, the scrollbar will appear. Of course all this assumes you are using an appropriate layout maanager.

Comment: I dont even see the text itself. the textarea is not visible. i don't see any text

Comment: I already suggested the problem is that you are not using a Layout Manager. I would guess the scrollpane has a 0 size so it is not painted. Fix your code to use Layout Managers and then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you are still having a problem.