# ScrollBar in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I want to create a scroll bar in the textarea but If I set the JPanel Layout to null, the scrollbar won't show!

**I tried**

```
JScrollPane scrollbar1 = 
  new JScrollPane(
    ta1,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

**But didn't work because of the null layout.**

Here is my current code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
public class app extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new app();
    }

    public app()
    {
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setLocation(0,0);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Application");           
        JPanel painel = new JPanel(null);           
        // Creating the Input
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("Some random text", 15);            
        tf1.setBounds(5,5,this.getWidth()-120,20);
        tf1.setColumns(10);
        tf1.setText("Omg");         
        painel.add(tf1);            
        // Creating the button          
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Send");          
        button1.setBounds(290, 5, 100, 19);         
        painel.add(button1);            
        // Creating the TextArea            
        JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea(15, 20);
        JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane();
        ta1.setBounds(5, 35, 385, 330);
        ta1.setLineWrap(true);
        ta1.setWrapStyleWord(true);         
        painel.add(ta1);
        this.add(painel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I want to make it work correctly. If someone can help me, leave a comment below please!

Comment: The correct way would be not using `null` layout. Anyway, you need to put the `TextArea` in the scroll pane, and the scroll pane where you want the combination to appear.

Comment: @Kiheru I said I tried to do that but it didn't work.

Comment: It does work, but you need to set the bounds of the scroll pane correctly since you're trying to create layout manually (yes, I tried it).

Comment: You should NOT be setting the bounds of the scroll pane. You should NOT be using a null layout. Null layouts cause problems like this. You SHOULD be using layout managers. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the JTextArea API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial for working examples that show you how to use Swing properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTextArea no scroll bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454442/jtextarea-no-scroll-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have corrected all the problems following is the working code. Please read comments for the changes.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class app extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new app();
    }

    public app() {
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLocation(0, 0);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Application");
        JPanel painel = new JPanel(null);
        // Creating the Input
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("Some random text", 15);
        tf1.setBounds(5, 5, this.getWidth() - 120, 20);
        tf1.setColumns(10);
        tf1.setText("Omg");

        // resultsTA,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        painel.add(tf1);
        // Creating the button
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Send");
        button1.setBounds(290, 5, 100, 19);
        painel.add(button1);
        // Creating the TextArea
        JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea(15, 20);
        JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(ta1,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);// Add your text area to scroll pane 
        ta1.setBounds(5, 35, 385, 330);
        ta1.setLineWrap(true);
        ta1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        scr.setBounds(20, 30, 100, 40);// You have to set bounds for all the controls and containers incas eof null layout
        painel.add(scr);// Add you scroll pane to container
        this.add(painel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT. Please read tutorial from oracle on Java. And start using appropriate layout manager...
Hope it helps

Comment: A `null` layout bad advice; see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass in your `JTextArea` to your `JScrollPane` constructor, and then add your `JScrollPane` object to your `Container` as opposed to just the `JTextArea`. So it would look something like this:

```
JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(ta1);
panel.add(scr);
```

Comment: +1, @JohnBlack, The code you posted is completely wrong. You should NOT be using null layouts and setBounds(). The layout manager will determine the size/location of the component. You are adding the text area to a panel instead of adding it to the viewport of the scrollpane. The code given to you by Josh is correct. The only other change is that you should not be creating the panel with a null layout. I have no idea where you copied that code from but you should ignore that websites examples. Read the Swing tutorial instead.

Answer (score 2):

`If someone can help me, leave a comment below please!`

- why please you are you going to smash with your head wall, `JScrollPane` is designated for Dynamic, Resizable `LayoutManager`, `AbsoluteLayout` can broken this its basic properties
- starting from top

  1. `public class app extends JFrame {`

     - `public class App {` ---> Java Naming Conventions
     - and not extends anything, create `JFrame` as local variable
  2. `new app();` ---> se Oracle tutorial Initial Thread
  3. create another `JPanel`, put there `JTextField` and `JButton`
  4. did you overlay something `tf1.setBounds(5,5,this.getWidth()-120,20);`
  5. `NullLayout` doesn't works correctly without using `Insets`
  6. change built_in `FlowLayout` for `JPanel painel = new JPanel(null);` to `BorderLayout`, there put `JScrollPane` with `JTextArea` to `CENTER area`
  7. you can to put `JScrollPane` with `JTextArea` to `JFrames CENTER area` directly and another `JPanel` with `JTextField` and `JButton` to `SOUTH` or `NORTH`, `JFrame` has `BorderLayout` implemented in API
  8. `JScrollPane` showing `JScrollbars` only in the case that its `Dimension` is smaller than `JComponent` placed there
  9. use `JFrame.pack()` instead of `setSize`, this line should be before `setVisible`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic example of many of @mKorbels [points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18292888/230513). Note how the default layout of `JPanel()`, `FlowLayout()`, uses the preferred size of its components. The call to `f.setSize()` is optional to force the scrollbar to appear.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }

    public App() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Application");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("Some random text", 15);
                tf1.setColumns(10);
                tf1.setText("Omg");
                panel.add(tf1);
                JButton button1 = new JButton("Send");
                panel.add(button1);
                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(15, 20);
                JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(ta);
                scr.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                ta.setLineWrap(true);
                ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                f.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                f.add(scr, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.pack();
                Dimension d = scr.getPreferredSize();
                f.setSize(d.width, d.height);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```